# Sound Processing frequency Dynamicly

Tags: sound, signal-processing

Would like to know if there is a method to call upon the frequency of a song at a given time for instance at 0:34 second the frequency is x ;

But to do this live meaning as long as the song is playing these numbers change;

The purpose is to use this output in another equation where for instance if the frequency > x then some condition is applied

```
soundms = AudioLocalMeasurements[audio, {"MFCC", "Loudness"}, Association, PartitionGranularity -> Quantity[1./30., "Seconds"]];

length = QuantityMagnitude@Round@UnitConvert[Quantity[Duration[audio]], "seconds"] - 2;

Manipulate[soundms["MFCC"][Range[1, length]][[All, 1]][[i]], {i, 1, length, 1}]
```

where "audio" is the audio file

this code simply exports loudness and mfcc of the audio file in a list of one dight per second of that audio clip

is there a way to run the audio clip and get that frequency updated as in

```
frequency:= "the frequency of the clip at this second"
```

so that when i recall that variable in any time the clip is running i get the frequency at that given moment?

I apologize for the mess

Comment: Is this related to the software Mathematica? If so, maybe give more detail, for instance, a concrete example.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Updated sorry for the mess

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using `Fourier` on short intervals?

Comment: @Hugh would you be kind to elaborate please?

Comment: `Fourier` calculates a spectrum of frequencies. You could select the largest as your frequency. The problem is the dynamic which must select an interval of data take the Fourier transform, find the maximum and display. The calculations are straightforward. When your say you wish to do this live what do you mean? Is the sound in the audio file in the computer and you just wish to get the frequency as it is playing?

Comment: @Hugh yes I'm trying to set an if condition where if the "playing" clip reaches a frequency value of x lets say 200 then the condition is activated then this condition is reactivated each time the clip frequency reaches said value thus i need this frequency value to be updated as the clip is playing

Comment: So the playing does not need to be in real time? You just need to create another time history that is true or false depending on the frequency content?

Comment: @Hugh preferably in real time as the clip plays

Comment: @Hugh here is the code I'm using to run a particle simulation study aiming to link the r to the high value of frequencies in an audio clip n = 1000;  r := RandomInteger[{1, n}];  f := (#/(.01 + Sqrt[#.#])) & /@ (x[[#]] - x) &;  s := With[{r1 = r}, p[[r1]] = r; q[[r1]] = r];  x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];  {p, q} = RandomInteger[{1, n}, {2, n}];  Graphics[{PointSize[0.007], Dynamic[If[r < 100, s];  Point[x = 0.995 x + 0.02 f[p] - 0.01 f[q]]]}, PlotRange -> 2]

Comment: Instead of recalling r as a random integer i wish to call the frequency or loudness of a certain audio clip as well as running the clip with the simulation but that's another endeavor

Comment: Could someone help?